# Activiti random behaviour

Tags: spring-boot, activiti

I'm creating a process instance as such:

```
processInstance = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKeyAndTenantId(key, initialParameters, tenantId + (isTest ? TEST_TENANT_SUFFIX : PRODUCTION_TENANT_SUFFIX));
```

which always returns a processInstance, but sometimes(seemingly randomly) the returned process instance does not exist in the database:

```
historyService.createHistoricProcessInstanceQuery().processInstanceId(processInstance.getId()).singleResult() == null

runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().processInstanceId(processInstance.getId()).singleResult() == null
```

I've also logged the mariadb queries and I've noticed that the times that the instance does not exist; no insert queries are logged in the database, so the process instance was not inserted and then deleted.

These problems started appearing after migrating to activiti6. Also I'm using activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of debugging I discovered that Activiti's command context was being manipulated in my code, which was causing the random behavior.